# Why use class << self in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can you explain why the developer is using `class << self` to add a methods to the base class?

[base.rb from the GeoPlanet Gem](http://github.com/carlosparamio/geoplanet/blob/master/lib/geoplanet/base.rb)

```
module GeoPlanet
  class Base
    class << self
      def build_url(resource_path, options = {})
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because he doesn't know that

```
def GeoPlanet::Base.build_url(resource_path, options = {}) end
```

would work just as well?

Well, they aren't 100% equivalent: if `GeoPlanet` doesn't exist, then the original snippet will create the module, but my version will raise a `NameError`. To work around that, you'd need to do this:

```
module GeoPlanet
  def Base.build_url(resource_path, options = {}) end
end
```

Which will of course raise a `NameError`, if `Base` doesn't exist. To work around *that*, you'd do:

```
module GeoPlanet
  class Base
    def self.build_url(resource_path, options = {}) end
  end
end
```

However you look at it, there's no *need* to use the singleton class syntax. Some people just simply prefer it.

Comment: Ok so the example from GeoPlanet is a little funky, right?  Your two examples are much more readable and I tend to go with the 'self.build_url' way.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is simply a matter of style/taste.  I like to use the `class << self` approach when I have a lot of class methods that I want to group together or provide some sort of visual separation from instance methods.

I would also use this approach if all my methods were class methods as the GeoPlanet author did.